# Which version of .net is installed on Windows Azure Servers?

Tags: azure

Does anyone know which version of .net is installed as I was trying to locate the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll on the Win 2008 R2 Server on Azure and could not find it in the GAC or elsewhere on the box.
Looks like only v3.5 is installed? I may be wrong...I need some experts on this....

Comment: This doesn't show the exact frameworks, but it would be helpful for you to understand what System Patches, etc..  [Windows Azure Guest OS Compatibility Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

On a Windows Azure Worker / Web Role is installed both the 3.5 SP1 and 4.0. Try to set the "Copy Local" on true.